# Encoding categorical variables in a numpy array through loop

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, encoding

I have a list of numpy array that contains categorical variables wherein I have used Label Encoding to encode these variables in an array, but my encoding results are something not expected and it shown like below

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

bin_ids = [np.array(['Horses', 'Cats', 'Dogs']), np.array(['Blue', 'Green', 'Red'])]

encoder  = LabelEncoder()

bin_ids_arr = []

for bin_id in bin_ids:
# flatten the array and encode the categorical values
  bin_ids_enc = encoder.fit_transform(bin_id.flatten()).reshape(bin_id.shape)
  bin_ids_arr.append(bin_ids_enc)
  
bin_ids_arr = np.array(bin_ids_arr)

print(bin_ids_arr)

Actual Output : [[2 0 1]
                [0 1 2]]
```

However, I'm expecting the output to be shown like below where each of the different categorical variables is assigned a different number continuously.

```
Expected Output : [[0 1 2]
                [3 4 5]]
```

Is there a way to get the encoding like the output above?

Comment: did you mean `[3 4 5]` instead of `[4 5 6]` ?

Comment: Oh, yes - I meant by `[3, 4, 5]` instead of `[4, 5, 6]`. I have corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to treat `bin_ids` as a continuous list of categories - it needs to be flattened  and passed to a single call of `LabelEncoder.fit_transform`. To obtain then categories/labels in the shape of the original array use `numpy.reshape`:

```
bin_cats = encoder.fit_transform(bin_ids.ravel()).reshape(bin_ids.shape)
print(bin_cats)
```

---

```
[[4 1 2]
 [0 3 5]]
```

---

**Note**, that the above result is unordered values as for encoding non-numerical labels `LabelEncoder` needs to ensure that the input labels are hashable and comparable, making that comparison lexicographically.

Comment: What do you mean by hashable and comparable ? I'm quite unclear about it. Does it mean that the labels should be in some order so that values appear in an order ?

Comment: @user3046211, read the doc https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html attentively and you'll see what I mentioned about